# Design pretty options menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, menu

I am trying to create an options menu in C# similar to those in Visual Studio, like this: 
[VS C# options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KY6C.jpg)

TabControl is close as it gives you a panel per menu entry, but I don't find a way to make it look like an expandable menu. Aligning the tabs left also rotates the text 90 degrees, which there seems to be no option to change. I was trying with regular MenuStrip, but there is no panel associated with each menu selection, and the menu is not expandable like in the Visual Studio Options menu.

Maybe I have overlooked something simple, I just need some pointers...

[image]

Comment: This is not a menu, of sure I don't know how that window has been coded. But perhaps here they have a treeview docked on the left, filled with the possible options. Whenever you click on a treeview item a relative panel full of the required controls is brought on the visible area of the window.

Comment: A TreeView in the left and one of many UserControls on the right side of a SplitControl. Just make sure they all can refer to a common data store!

Comment: It is just a plain TreeView, the exact same one you got in the Winforms toolbox.  It uses the "explorer" visual styles theme, SetWindowTheme() pinvoke call.